# Sorting String CompareTo

Tags: java

I am Java beginer and I have to make a program that enters a String using command line and then prints the number of the entered words, the entered words and the sorted words. I can do everything except the sorting. I know I have to use compareTo, but I don't know how to make the method work. Would love to get some help!

Here's my code so far:

```
class Sort{
    public static void main(String args[]){
         int count=args.length;
         System.out.println("\nYou've enetered "+count+" word and they are:");
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
         {System.out.print(args[i]+" ");}
         System.out.println("\nThe sorted words are:");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `Arrays#sort` or do you have to implement a sort algorithm on your own?

Comment: A number of stock java mechanisms could do this for you fairly easily, the simplest of which luiggi has just hinted at

Comment: I have to use the String method compareTo...

Comment: Then you have to implement a sorting algorithm. Do you know any sorting algorithm?

Comment: Not, really. I'm really a beginer..

Comment: @DanielaGocheva String already has compareTo. You can use that for your need.

Comment: @Sas OP's asking **how** he/she can do that.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: If I had 2 Strings I was going to do it myself, but the command line entering is confusing me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are required to use `compareTo`, you can implement `Collections.sort`.

After all values are added in your array, just provide this array to `Collections.sort()` along with a custom `Comparator`. But the problem is that the `Collections.sort()` wouldn't accept an `String` array, so you also have to convert it to a list using `Arrays.asList(yourArray)` method.

Suppose this is your array,

```
String [] args = new String[]{"dddd","cccc","bbbb", "aaaa"};
```

Now let's use `Collections.sort` after converting your array to a list and provide it with a `Comparator`.

```
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(args),new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
});
```

simple, isn't it ?

If you want to print the sorted values now,

```
for (String p : args ){
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

***Outputs***

```
aaaa
bbbbb
cccc
dddd
```

Just for your information, if you want to sort in reverse order, replace
`return o1.compareTo(o2)` with `return o2.compareTo(o1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.sort for sorting and Arrays.toString to convert to String the given array:

```
class Sort{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.printf("\nYou've enetered %d words and they are:", args.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));

        Arrays.sort(args);
        System.out.println("\nThe sorted words are:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
 }
```

Comment: OP clearly stated he needs to use `compareTo()`, and doing what likely is his homework for him isn't going to benefit him in any way.

Comment: @Drew `sort` uses `comapreTo(...)`. Sure, you may be right, but let the OP mention this him/herself.

Comment: @BartKiers it's stated in the question: *I can do everything except the sorting. **I know I have to use compareTo**, but I don't know how to make the method work.*

Comment: How do you suppose to implement `compareTo` for the `String` class?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, like I said, that may well be the case, but the OP didn't explicitly mention s/he can't use the built-in sort. The OP might not be aware of `Arrays.sort(...)` and it's *that* fact s/he means. Again, it's speculation. What's wrong with letting the OP clarify?

Comment: If I had 2 Strings I was going to do it myself, but the command line entering is confusing me...

Comment: @manzur the question is not about implementing `compareTo` for `String` class. It's about sorting a `String[]` using `String#compareTo`. This looks like homework, so seems like OP has to implement a sorting algorithm like bubble sort or quicksort, depending on his/her knowledge on the topic.

Comment: @BartKiers OP has clarified this in comments on the question but I cannot edit the question since I approved the edit before reading the comments.